# difference between regular and bipartite centrality measures in networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have noticed recently that NetworkX has bipartite versions of centrality measures such as betweenness, closeness, etc. The documentation mentions that these are normalising distances differently, for example:

> https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.closeness_centrality

But besides the difference in normalization, is this difference ever going to change the relative rank of nodes under the different versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be not too difficult to construct an example for each of the three implemented centrality measures (degree, betweenness, closeness) for bipartite networks, where the normalisation will also affect the relative rank of the nodes.

The easiest one is probably [degree](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.degree_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.bipartite.centrality.degree_centrality), where the degree of each node is divided by the size of the "other" node set. Then, we take the graph:

```
0<->A
1<->A
2<->B
```

Standard degree centralities:

```
c_s(0) = c_s(1) = c_s(2) = c_s(B) = 1; c_s(A) = 2
```

With normalisation for bipartite graphs:

```
c_s(0) = c_s(1) = c_s(2) = 1/2; (!=) c_s(B) = 1/3; c_s(A) = 2/3
```

So now we have c_s(B) < c_s(0).